# Using a variable to initialise an object

Tags: c#, string, variables, object, struct

This might end up being a quick 'can't be done' however I've looked about and can't find the answer to my specific query.

My issue is I have a struct for holding details of students, now say I have two students, one called Mike the other called Dave and I want to get the details of each on screen I have a method in my struct like so:

```
public struct student{
   public String name, course;
   public int year, studentno;

   public void displayDetails(){
        Console.WriteLine("Name: "+name);
        Console.WriteLine("Course: "+course);
        Console.WriteLine("Student Number: "+studentno);
        Console.WriteLine("Year of Study: "+year);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to Continue....");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now to display details I can use either say, Mike.displayDetails(); or Dave.displayDetails();

Is there a way I can ask for a user input for a name and then use that name to get the correct student? For example I want to use:

```
Console.Write("Please enter students name: ");
String surname = Console.ReadLine();
```

and then somehow use:

```
surname.displayDetails();
```

to display the correct student, is this doable?

Answer (score 6):

It would be doable with an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the string type, but it certainly wouldn't be recommended. Why not use LINQ to locate a student with a given surname over a collection of students?

```
List<Student> students 
   = new List<Student>
      { 
         new Student { Surname = "Smith" }, 
         new Student { Surname = "Jones" } 
      };

Student studentJones = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Surname == "Jones");
```

Other points to note:

- Use a class, not a struct unless you have a good reason to do so
- Use PascalCase for method and type names
- Avoid the use of public fields, use properties instead

Answer (score 3):

You can put them into a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, Student> dict = new Dictionary<string, Student>();
dict.Add("Dave", Dave);
dict.Add("Mike", Mike);
string surname = Console.ReadLine();
dict[surname].DisplayDetails();
```

BTW, retrieval from a dictionary is generally faster (O(1)) than looking through the list (O(n)), which `FirstOrDefault` does.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and derive from KeyedCollection.  Set the key to be the student's name.  As each student is added to the collection, you can simply call:

```
Console.Write(myCollection[surname].DisplayDetails());



public class Students : KeyedCollection<string, Student>
{
    // The parameterless constructor of the base class creates a 
    // KeyedCollection with an internal dictionary. For this code 
    // example, no other constructors are exposed.
    //
    public Students () : base() {}

    // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden,
    // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the
    // keys from the items. The input parameter type is the 
    // second generic type argument, in this case OrderItem, and 
    // the return value type is the first generic type argument,
    // in this case string.
    //
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Student item)
    {
        // In this example, the key is the student's name.
        return item.Name;
    }
}
```